# Use of STL algorithms in a tile matching game logic

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I have made a tile matching game. It has a Board object that holds a vector of card objects and delegates events to them. Board event handling has following code in it:

```
// Counting logic-driving card states
int cardFaceUpCounter = 0;
std::vector<Card*> faceUpCards(2);

// Checking for logic-driving card states 
for (auto& card : this->boardMatrix)
{
    if (this->isCardInAnim(&card))
    {
        return;
    }
    if (this->isCardFaceUp(&card))
    {
        ++cardFaceUpCounter;
        faceUpCards[cardFaceUpCounter - 1] = &card;
    }       
}
```

I've just finished studying Beautiful C++ by Kate Gregory on Pluralsight.
She argues that we should avoid writing loops, and should use the STL algorithm header as much as possible. 
I find her argument and approach very compelling, thus I have tried to refactor my latest pet project to reflect her teachings.

The example above is where I just can't see how I can use STL algorithms to both communicate the intent better and keep the performance - single loop instead of two or three loops, albeit hidden in the algorithm calls.

The second question would be if single loop efficiency can't be achieved using STL algorithms would you still prefer that approach for readability sake.

Comment: Why are you expecting two and only two face up cards? You could write this as a standard transformation of one container to another.

Comment: My game is set up that only two cards can be up at any time. Event can trigger only one card turn, so if two cards are detected to be up, the next event(click), either discards them if same or turns them back if different.

Comment: It's usually better to use `push_back` in case your assumptions are wrong. Plus it makes your algorithm more generic.

Comment: If my asumptions are wrong my game logic breaks, it looked easier for me to find a fault if my code breaks than if my logic breaks. But i will further research ur comment. Thanks, sincerely.

Comment: Also, do you think my reasoning is valid?

Comment: You can use `std::any_of` and just give it the same body as a lambda.

Comment: I've done that for card animation check, and i feel it comunicates what im doing much better, but im still left with the lower part of the loop.

Comment: You can just put the lower part of the loop in the same call to `std::any_of`?

Comment: Wont any_of return true after the first condition is met. I dont know how many cards are up. Can you please provide an answer if you have an idea how to do it. I might be missing something obvious. I'm quite tired :)

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted? The return statement in you current example would mean that if card number 2 is `inAnim` then the loop would stop there and no cards after that would be checked for `faceUp`.

Comment: yes, it's an event loop. if there is a card in animation, i dont allow events to get processed. U have to painfully watch out the animation. but if there are no animations, there can be cards facing up, and i need to know how many are facing up so i can decide how to delegate the event.

Comment: this used to be 2 loops, first checking to break for anim, and then doing the counting, but it seemed more efficient this way. I might be wrong, my decision is completely intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I was thinking.

```
int cardFaceUpCounter = 0;
std::vector<Card*> faceUpCards(2);

if (std::any_of(boardMatrix.begin(), boardMatrix.end(), [&](auto& card) {
    if (isCardFaceUp(&card))
        faceUpCards[cardFaceUpCounter++] = &card;

    return isCardInAnim(&card);    
})) return;
```

Comment: Wow, nice :) I'll accept it in the morning, when i get to dig some more into the problem. Thanks :) for the sake of completeness, you can add if(any_of()) return; since anim breaks my loop.

Comment: I think this answers my first question. But do you think this code is more readable than what i wrote? I know its an oppinion I'm asking for but, sometimes you can't without them :)

Comment: I tried writing something more expressive but i end up writing a find_all func, a std:: find_if in a loop that saves to a vector. It hardly seems worth the trouble.

Comment: @AntonioDropulić Since you want to end the outer function, I would probably go for just a loop myself.

Comment: I would avoid to use side effects in an `std::any_of`.

Answer (score 1):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it would be something like:

```
std::vector<Card*> faceUpCards = this->boardMatrix
    | ranges::view::take_while([this](const auto& card){ return !isCardInAnim(&card);})
    | ranges::view::filter([this](const auto& card){ return isCardFaceUp(&card); })
    | ranges::view::transform([](auto& e){ return &e; });
```

With only STL, I would do something like:

```
auto it = std::find_if(boardMatrix.begin(), boardMatrix.end(),
                       [this](const auto& card){ return isCardInAnim(&card);});
std::vector<Card*> faceUpCards(std::distance(boardMatrix.begin(), it), nullptr);
std::transform(boardMatrix.begin(), it,
               faceUpCards.begin(),
               [](auto& card){ return &card;});
faceUpCards.erase(std::remove_if(faceUpCards.begin(), faceUpCards.end(),
                                [this](const auto& card){ return !isCardFaceUp(&card); }),
                  faceUpCards.end());
```

Comment: Tell me If I'm reading your code good. You expect all of the face up cards to be between begin and card in anim, and you expect all cards between begin and card in anim to be up.

Also thanks for the range example, but I'm currently trying to master STL - newbie problems :)

Comment: I upvoted for the range - v3 lib, not sure if the stl example is correct.

Comment: Indeed, I missed the filtering in both case about `isCardFaceUp`. Fixed.